# how to stack one image over another in css?

Tags: html, css

I wan to stack image b over image a and image b will automatically go with the image a no matter where it move.This is my code

```
  <div id="down">
  <img id="yes" src="http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/hi%2c-loser-wallpapers_17839_1024x768.jpg" >

  <div id="up">
  <img id="no" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/SMirC-hi.svg/320px-SMirC-hi.svg.png">
  </div>

 </div>
```

and here is my css:

```
 #down{

         float: right;

     }


     #up{

        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;

     }
```

i thought the image b will also float with image a and have a absolute position of 10px from top and 10px from left of image b. what why it is not like that????hope you know what i mean

Comment: do you think `src="imageb"` will work?

Comment: @dramasea it's working http://tinkerbin.com/boyNUDIO

Comment: @pls use my img instead, u will know what i mean

Comment: @dramasea can you post the image of your desired result what exactly you are looking that would be much better for us to understand your requirement...

Comment: ok, compare this http://tinkerbin.com/Ts0lzGRc   to the code i wrote, i juz wan to know why float not work

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add your image properly imagea.png or imagea.jpg what?

Add z-index here

```
#up{
z-index:1;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
```

}

And also add this one

```
#down{
     z-index:0;
         float: right;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position:absolute` instead of float.

Here is the working sample: [Position in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/54777/)

To my understanding `float` does not work `left` and `right` positioning, only `absolute` positioning does. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.